# How can I give n function's parameters if I have a vector of these parameters only?

Tags: c++

I have a vector, length of it is n. A function looks like
`int foo(int x_1, int x_2, ..., int x_n)`. Are there any ways to turn this vector to a nice object?

I don't know what I should do

Python has the simple construction which helps to separate smth. May be C++ has the same one?

```py
a, b = map(int, input().split())
```

I expect for a kind of this construction

Comment: you tag C++ but in you code snippet you have python. Which one is it?

Comment: @bolov The way I understand this question (and which makes it a valid one) is "how to achieve in C++ what this Python code would do in Python".

Comment: @Angew great. He should [edit] the question to specify this if that is indeed the case.

Comment: also `int foo(int x_1, int x_2, ..., int x_n)` doesn't make much sense in C++

Comment: This would mean, that you know at compile-time, which function you want to call. So you need to know the number of arguments at compile-time. Then you can go the happy path of templates. There has to be a combination of variadic templates and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55281612/3233393).

Comment: "Are there any ways to turn this vector to a nice object?" ???

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<int> my_vec;

// here init my_vec

// now pass it to foo

if(my_vec.size() != n){
    // handle invalid input
}
else{
   int return_val = foo(my_vec[0], my_vec[1], .... , my_vec[n-1]);
}

// enjoy!
```

Comment: @bolov Yes, indeed. But in the OP's case, `n` is known at compile time - it's the number of parameters `foo` accepts.